# org-babel, org-table and package-install: “Package `dired+-' is unavailable

Tags: package, org-babel, org-table

I'm currently using org-mode to organize my init files — specifically, working off a fork of [emacs24-starter-kit](http://eschulte.github.com/emacs24-starter-kit/). Recently, I had come across the idea of using org-tables to organize some of my things — I've had great success in configuring `package-archive`, `package-pinned-packages` and even `pretty-symbols-alist` for `elisp-mode` and `lisp-interaction-mode`.

I've hit a snag, though, in trying to create a list of packages that *must* be installed on every instance of emacs I use, on all machines I have emacs installed. The code looks like this on org-mode:

```
#+NAME:package-settings
| name               | repository   |
|--------------------+--------------|
| dired+             | MELPA        |
| form-feed          | MELPA-stable |
| org-bullets        | MELPA-stable |
| org-plus-contrib   | org          |
| powerline          | MELPA-stable |
| rainbow-delimiters | MELPA-stable |
| yasnippet          | MELPA-stable |
| color-theme        | MELPA        |

#+begin_src emacs-lisp :var name=package-settings[,0] repository=package-settings[,1]
  (when (require 'package nil 'noerror)
    (progn
      (require 'cl)
      (setq package-pinned-packages (pairlis name repository))
      (setq *pkg-to-install
            (let (result)
              (dolist (entry name result)
                (setq result (append result (list (make-symbol entry)))))))
      (dolist (pkg *pkg-to-install)
        (when (not (package-installed-p pkg))
          (package-install pkg)))
      (package-initialize))) ; and reinitialize again
#+end_src
```

However, when I do this, I get the following error message:

```
package-compute-transaction: Package `dired+-' is unavailable
```

Pressing `C-x C-e` on the affected sexp (i.e. `(dolist pkg...`) gets me this:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Package `dired+-' is unavailable")
  signal(error ("Package `dired+-' is unavailable"))
  error("Package `%s-%s' is unavailable" dired+ "")
  package-compute-transaction(nil ((dired+)))
  package-install(dired+)
  (progn (package-install pkg))
  (if (not (package-installed-p pkg)) (progn (package-install pkg)))
  (while --dolist-tail-- (setq pkg (car --dolist-tail--)) (if (not  (package-installed-p pkg)) (progn (package-install pkg))) (setq --dolist-tail-- (cdr --dolist-tail--)))
  (let ((--dolist-tail-- *pkg-to-install) pkg) (while --dolist-tail-- (setq pkg (car --dolist-tail--)) (if (not (package-installed-p pkg)) (progn (package-install pkg))) (setq --dolist-tail-- (cdr --dolist-tail--))))
  eval((let ((--dolist-tail-- *pkg-to-install) pkg) (while --dolist-tail-- (setq pkg (car --dolist-tail--)) (if (not (package-installed-p pkg)) (progn (package-install pkg))) (setq --dolist-tail-- (cdr --dolist-tail--)))) nil)
  eval-last-sexp-1(nil)
  eval-last-sexp(nil)
  call-interactively(eval-last-sexp nil nil)
  command-execute(eval-last-sexp)
```

I honestly don't know what could be wrong here. I managed to finangle the fact that `org-babel` exports the vars as `(let ((name (quote ("dired+" "form-feed" ...)))...)...)` by using `make-symbol`, but I've hit the limit in terms of my (admittedly still rather sketchy at places) understanding of elisp.

Comment: That error-message means "package-install doesn't know where to find dired+" (ignore the suffix "-"), you can solve this with `(package-refresh-contents)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :var name=package-settings[,0] repository=package-settings[,1]
  (require 'package)
  (require 'cl-lib)

  (setq package-pinned-packages (cl-pairlis name repository))

  (let ((pkgs (mapcar #'intern name)))
    (mapc (lambda (pkg)
            (unless (package-installed-p pkg)
              (unless (assoc pkg package-archive-contents)
                (package-refresh-contents))
              (package-install pkg)))
          pkgs))

  (package-initialize)
#+end_src
```

Comment: Okay, so that does work, which is great. Thank you! Ohhh, so *that's* what I was doing wrong, I was using `make-symbol` instead of `intern` (replacing `make-symbol` in my old code causes *everything* to fall into place). And rather than making a temporary symbol to hold on to the list of package symbols, you've used `let` and `mapcar` to transform `name` from a list of strings to a list of symbols, and *then*, since all we need are the side-effects, just used `mapc` to run through the whole “check if `package-installed-p`, and then… wait, `assoc` is used for what, again?

Comment: The `(unless (assoc pkg...` test just runs once, and if it fails it doesn't try to run `package-refresh-contents` again, doesn't it? So if I have gibberish or misspell a package name in the table, it'll just refresh the package list once every time, right?

Comment: You know what, I think the basic structure works out pretty well, and your use of `intern` basically solves my problem. Thank you very much! I think I'll just mark this as the correct answer.

Comment: That tests if package.el knows `pkg`, if doesn't, call `(package-refresh-contents)` to fetch all packages's descriptions, if does, do nothing. So if you misspell a package name, `(package-refresh-contents)` will be called once for it, and then `package-install` will interrupt, further package will not be installed.  `mapc` and `mapcar` are sequential, not parallel.